# how to escape double quote in xml String generated by jaxb

Tags: java, spring, jaxb

Basically I need to build an xml file and then submit the xml request to a restTemplate post action as follows:

```
final RestTemplate restTemplate1 = new RestTemplate();
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
        MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
        converter.setSupportedMediaTypes(Collections.singletonList(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML));
        messageConverters.add(converter);
        restTemplate1.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);
    HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
    headers.setBasicAuth("okmAdmin", "admin");
    headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);


    JAXBContext context = null;
    context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Folder.class);
    Marshaller mar = null;
    mar = context.createMarshaller();
    mar.setProperty("jaxb.encoding", "Unicode");
    mar.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.FALSE);

    //Print XML String to Console
    StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

    Folder folder = new Folder();
    folder.setPath("/okm:root/test4");

    //Write XML to StringWriter
    mar.marshal(folder, sw);

    String xmlContent = sw.toString();

    System.out.println(xmlContent);

    HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(xmlContent, headers);

    ResponseEntity<Folder> response = restTemplate1.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/OpenKM/services/rest/folder/create", request, Folder.class);
```

The xml generated is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="Unicode" standalone="yes"?><folder><path>/okm:root/test4</path><permissions>0</permissions><subscribed>false</subscribed><hasChildren>false</hasChildren><style>0</style></folder>
```

However when the xml is submitted by the resttemplate,I got the following errors:

```
2022-12-05 16:50:21.121 ERROR 15764 --- [nio-8082-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.web.client.HttpClientErrorException$BadRequest: 400 : "JAXBException occurred : Unexpected character '"' (code 34) in prolog; expected '<'<EOL> at [row,col {unknown-source}]: [1,1]. "] with root cause
```

Based on the error message it looks like i need to escape the double quote.

How can I escape it pls?

Comment: Please don't delete questions only to repost them with more information. Edit your existing question instead next time. Now, what does the API *actually expect*? Are you sure you want "Unicode" as the encoding? (I'd expect UTF-8 to be more common.) Have you looked with Wireshark or something similar at what's *actually being posted*? My guess is that your XML string is being escaped as JSON...

Comment: "Based on the error message it looks like i need to escape the double quote." - No, based on the error message you're *sending* a double-quote, when the server is actually *expecting* a `<` as the start of the XML. That's why I've suggested you should see what's actually being sent on the wire.

Answer (score 0):

Try using StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml() like the following :

```
HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(StringEscapeUtils.escapeXml(xmlContent), headers);
```

Comment: Hi I have  tried it but got same error msg

Answer (score 0):

I manage to fix the issue by changing the following code:
remove this:

```
MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter converter = new MappingJackson2HttpMessageConverter();
```

Added this:

```
 messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());
```

And instead of casting the object to Folder I have used String:

```
     ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate1.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/OpenKM/services/rest/folder/create", request, String.class);
```

The complete code is as follows:

```
final RestTemplate restTemplate1 = new RestTemplate();
        List<HttpMessageConverter<?>> messageConverters = new ArrayList<>();
        messageConverters.add(new StringHttpMessageConverter());

    restTemplate1.setMessageConverters(messageConverters);

        HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
        headers.setBasicAuth("okmAdmin", "admin");
        headers.setContentType(MediaType.APPLICATION_XML);


        JAXBContext context = null;
        context = JAXBContext.newInstance(Folder.class);
        Marshaller mar = null;
        mar = context.createMarshaller();

        mar.setProperty(Marshaller.JAXB_FORMATTED_OUTPUT, Boolean.FALSE);

        //Print XML String to Console
        StringWriter sw = new StringWriter();

        Folder folder = new Folder();
        folder.setPath("/okm:root/test23");

        //Write XML to StringWriter
        mar.marshal(folder, sw);


        HttpEntity<String> request = new HttpEntity<String>(xmlString, headers);


        ResponseEntity<String> response = restTemplate1.postForEntity("http://localhost:8080/OpenKM/services/rest/folder/create", request, String.class);

        System.out.println(response);


    }
```

I am adding this in case if someone else have the same issue.

Thanks